# RxJava with MVVM: MutableLiveData w/ setValue() vs. LiveDataReactiveStreams

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata, android-mvvm

Let's say you have a MVVM app with a UI layer, a ViewModel, and a Repository. Say that in your repository, you're getting some data from an API with `Single` Retrofit calls, and transforming it into a UI-ready viewstate object.

The way I see it, you have two main choices (assuming you want to use LiveData in the UI layer, I am not including the option of observing Rx types from the UI):

1. Expose your Rx `Observable` from the repository, and `subscribe()` to it in the ViewModel. In the subscriber's `onNext()`, use `setValue()` to wrap your viewstate object in a `MutableLiveData`, and expose that as a non-mutable `LiveData` to the UI. Manually dispose the subscription in `onCleared()`.
2. Expose your Rx `Observable` from the repository and have the ViewModel subscribe to it with `LiveDataReactiveStreams`'s `fromPublisher()`, in which case manual disposal is unnecessary, and there is no `MutableLiveData` at all. *However*, `LiveDataReactiveStreams` subscribes/unsubscribes whenever `LiveData` becomes active/inactive (aka has at least one observer), so this option would halt all stream processing on every config change, unlike (1) (although, only if the `Observable` is cold).

Is this analysis incorrect or incomplete in any way? Are there any other important differences between these two approaches?

Comment: I think, under following circumstances, this is complete list of possible solutions. I personally use solution no. 1. Actually, there is no need to do disposal of subscribers manually, but let `ViewModel` do it for you automatically. We have implemented this kind of behaviour in our MVVM arch repository https://github.com/thefuntasty/mvvm-android